# Use Content Type for EditForm.aspx

Tags: content-type, edit-form, newform

I have a custom list with 2 content types.

- The first user to add an item will use ContentType1 so that only necessary fields are shown.
- The next user comes in and edits that same item, but I want them to use ContentType2 with the additional fields.

How can I set the Content Type on each form without using SharePoint Designer? We are not supporting SPD here.

Answer (score 1):

If both content types are attached to the list, then the default editform will automatically have an option to toggle the content type on edit. Set the default content type on the list to ContentType1 so any Add Item links will default to that. Then when user 2 comes along, he or she can toggle the Content Type field on the editform and switch to ContentType2.

Laura has documented this on her blog before, http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=43&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0

Comment: That's great but I was hoping to do it automatically without user interaction. I guess I can add some jQuery to switch that drop down on loading of editform